# Twitter Feeds for a PHP Website

Tags: php, twitter

Can I ask how can I show my tweets in my website? Like the Twitter feeds thingie. I want to have a table where in it will just show my Twitter account's tweets. Thanks guys!

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422879/best-twitter-php-library

Answer (score 1):

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/{yourfeed}.rss');
 // display each tweet
 foreach ($xml->channel->item as $tweet) 
{
   echo $tweet->title . '<br />';
}
```

Tons of other solution which can be found just by simple google search.

Check this

http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php

Answer (score 1):

Twitter provides a javascript widget that you can copy and insert into your website.  Is this what you're looking for http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Post this php above the head of your html:

```
<?php
//Replace XXXXX with your twitter username
$twitterUsername = "XXXXX";
//Change number to amount of tweets you would like to display
$amountToShow = 5;
$twitterRssFeedUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$twitterUsername.'&count='.$amountToShow;

$twitterPosts = false;
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($twitterRssFeedUrl);
if(is_object($xml)){
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $twit){
    if(is_array($twitterPosts) && count($twitterPosts)==$amountToShow){
    break;
}
$d['title'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->title,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$description = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->description,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
if(strtolower(substr($description,0,strlen($twitterUsername))) == strtolower($twitterUsername)){
    $description = substr($description,strlen($twitterUsername)+1);
}
$d['description'] = $description;
$d['pubdate'] = strtotime($twit->pubDate);
$d['guid'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->guid,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$d['link'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->link,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$twitterPosts[]=$d;
}
}else{

die('Can`t fetch the feed you requested');
}
 
?>
```

Post this in the body of your html:

```
<ul>
<?php
if(is_array($twitterPosts)){
echo '';
foreach($twitterPosts as $post){ 
$data = $post['description'];

 echo '<li>'.$data.'. ';
 echo '<a href="'.$post['link'].'" class="timestamp">Posted '.date('F j, Y, g:i a',$post['pubdate']).'</a></li>';
}
echo '';
}else{
    echo 'No Twitter posts have been made';//Error message
}

?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a couple more functions you can add the relative time (ie "Yesterday" "2 weeks ago" etc) and convert urls and usernames into links.

Insert the code below into the top of your php file:

```
 <?php
    ######################################
    ## DISPLAY TWITTER FEED
    ######################################

    //Replace XXXXX with your twitter username
    $twitterUsername = "XXXXX";
    //Change number to amount of tweets you would like to display
    $amountToShow = 5;

    $twitterRssFeedUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$twitterUsername.'&count='.$amountToShow;

    $twitterPosts = false;
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file($twitterRssFeedUrl);
    if(is_object($xml)){
        foreach($xml->channel->item as $twit){
        if(is_array($twitterPosts) && count($twitterPosts)==$amountToShow){
        break;
    }
    $d['title'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->title,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    $description = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->description,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    if(strtolower(substr($description,0,strlen($twitterUsername))) == strtolower($twitterUsername)){
        $description = substr($description,strlen($twitterUsername)+1);
    }
    $d['description'] = $description;
    $d['pubdate'] = strtotime($twit->pubDate);
    $d['guid'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->guid,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    $d['link'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->link,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    $twitterPosts[]=$d;
    }
    }else{

    die('Can`t fetch the feed you requested');
    }
     


    ######################################
    ## REPLACE URLS AND USERS WITH LINKS
    ######################################

function hyperlinks($text) {
    // Props to Allen Shaw & webmancers.com
    // match protocol://address/path/file.extension?some=variable&another=asf%
    //$text = preg_replace("/\b([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[a-z][a-z0-9\_\.\-]*[a-z]{2,6}[a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\?\&\%]*)\b/i","<a href=\"$1\" class=\"twitter-link\">$1</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\b([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[\w_.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}[\/\w\-~.?=&%#+$*!]*)\b/i',"<a href=\"$1\" class=\"twitter-link\">$1</a>", $text);
    // match www.something.domain/path/file.extension?some=variable&another=asf%
    //$text = preg_replace("/\b(www\.[a-z][a-z0-9\_\.\-]*[a-z]{2,6}[a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\?\&\%]*)\b/i","<a href=\"http://$1\" class=\"twitter-link\">$1</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\b(?<!:\/\/)(www\.[\w_.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}[\/\w\-~.?=&%#+$*!]*)\b/i',"<a href=\"http://$1\" class=\"twitter-link\">$1</a>", $text);    

    // match name@address
    $text = preg_replace("/\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]*[a-zA-Z]*\@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]*[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\b/i","<a href=\"mailto://$1\" class=\"twitter-link\">$1</a>", $text);
        //mach #trendingtopics. Props to Michael Voigt
    $text = preg_replace('/([\.|\,|\:|\¡|\¿|\>|\{|\(]?)#{1}(\w*)([\.|\,|\:|\!|\?|\>|\}|\)]?)\s/i', "$1<a href=\"http://twitter.com/#search?q=$2\" class=\"twitter-link\">#$2</a>$3 ", $text);
    return $text;
}

function twitter_users($text) {
       $text = preg_replace('/([\.|\,|\:|\¡|\¿|\>|\{|\(]?)@{1}(\w*)([\.|\,|\:|\!|\?|\>|\}|\)]?)\s/i', "$1<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$2\" class=\"twitter-user\">@$2</a>$3 ", $text);
       return $text;
}     






    ######################################
    ## DISPLAY RELATIVE DATES
    ######################################

//props to Osman Üngür for this (http://goo.gl/FrEMp)
function time2str($ts)
{
    if(!ctype_digit($ts))
        $ts = strtotime($ts);

    $diff = time() - $ts;
    if($diff == 0)
        return 'now';
    elseif($diff > 0)
    {
        $day_diff = floor($diff / 86400);
        if($day_diff == 0)
        {
            if($diff < 60) return 'just now';
            if($diff < 120) return '1 minute ago';
            if($diff < 3600) return floor($diff / 60) . ' minutes ago';
            if($diff < 7200) return '1 hour ago';
            if($diff < 86400) return floor($diff / 3600) . ' hours ago';
        }
        if($day_diff == 1) return 'Yesterday';
        if($day_diff < 7) return $day_diff . ' days ago';
        if($day_diff == 7) return '1 week ago';
        if($day_diff < 31) return ceil($day_diff / 7) . ' weeks ago';
        if($day_diff < 60) return 'last month';
        return date('F Y', $ts);
    }
    else
    {
        $diff = abs($diff);
        $day_diff = floor($diff / 86400);
        if($day_diff == 0)
        {
            if($diff < 120) return 'in a minute';
            if($diff < 3600) return 'in ' . floor($diff / 60) . ' minutes';
            if($diff < 7200) return 'in an hour';
            if($diff < 86400) return 'in ' . floor($diff / 3600) . ' hours';
        }
        if($day_diff == 1) return 'Tomorrow';
        if($day_diff < 4) return date('l', $ts);
        if($day_diff < 7 + (7 - date('w'))) return 'next week';
        if(ceil($day_diff / 7) < 4) return 'in ' . ceil($day_diff / 7) . ' weeks';
        if(date('n', $ts) == date('n') + 1) return 'next month';
        return date('F Y', $ts);
    }
}

  ?>
```

Then post the following code in the body of your html:

```
<ul>
<?php
if(is_array($twitterPosts)){
echo '';
foreach($twitterPosts as $post){ 
$data = hyperlinks($post['description']);
$data = twitter_users($data);

 echo '<li>'.$data.'. ';
 echo '<a href="'.$post['link'].'" class="timestamp">Posted '.time2str(date($post['pubdate'])).'</a></li>';
}
echo '';
}else{
    echo 'No Twitter posts have been made';//Error message
}

?>
</ul>
```